# Change the size of a symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to have the | the correct size for the situation and since I can't use \left and \right, I tried to use \large but it didn't change. Help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,tikz,fancyhdr,cancel,enumerate,array,booktabs,setspace,pgf,tikz,fancyhdr,graphicx,color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\[ I(\theta)=-\E\left\lbrace\frac{d^2\ln{\left[f(X|\theta)\right]}}{d\theta^2}|\theta\right\rbrace\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: `\large` really only affects text.  for delimiters, there are `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`. and \Bigg` that are nondirectional, and also `\bigl`, `\bigr`, etc., to indicate left or right versions.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! Please always make sure to remove all packages that don’t seem to have any influence on the problem; see my answer at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason for using `\left` and `\right` in the inner formula. I would also omit the square brackets. For the big bar, use `\;\middle|\;`. For the inner bar, `\mid` provides a good spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
I(\theta)=
-E\left\lbrace
  \frac{d^2\ln f(X\mid\theta)}{d\theta^2}
  \;\middle|\;
  \theta
  \right\rbrace
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the difference between `\left\lbrace` and `\left\{`?

Comment: @Jubobs The number of characters needed. :)

Comment: Thanks! And I understand about the inner left and right and getting rid of the square brackets, they're there to keep with the format of the rest of the document, there are brackets strictly defining the subject of each ln, sin, cos etc...

Comment: @DannyBland Mathematica writes `Sin[x]`, mathematicians don't. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\lvert` and `\rvert` for `|` as in $\lvert x \rvert$, or `\mid` as in $a \mid b$. Those give the right spacing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the problem.

Comment: @egreg It does if you replace the \mid by \mid|.